# adding separate equation to the a given data range

Tags: date, dplyr, time, weather

I am new to r and looking for the answer to the following question.
I have a weather data for some years (say 2001-2010) and I am applying some equation to the data (just like linear one), with purpose of multiplying data with some slope say (m) and adding constant in order to get the desired form. At certain points, I feel the equation should be changed and new one should be applied (like by from August 2004-January the equation should be "" y'=0.05(y)+7 "" instead of "" y'=1.12(y) + 4 "" a general equation for the dataset of a particular column say temperature).

Any help provided in adding separate equation to some or a given column of the data set in a particular date range would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution would be a combo of `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::case_when`. The `mutate()` function can make a new column in your dataset, and the `case_when` will let you change your function according to, for example, year.

Here's some play data :

```
df <- data.frame(
  temp_ob = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 14, sd = 1),
  year = rep(c(2001:2010), 10)
)
```

And here's a simple example where `case_when` changes how the new variable is calculated depending on the year in that row of the dataframe.

```r
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate( # this is making a new column
    # you can have more lines or more complicated conditions, but this uses 2
    temp_ob_new = dplyr::case_when( 
      year %in% c(2001:2004)  ~ (0.05*(temp_ob) + 7),
      year %in% c(2005:2010)  ~ (1.12*(temp_ob) + 4)
    )
  )

head(df)

#   temp_ob year temp_ob_new
#1 13.20622 2001    7.660311
#2 12.33559 2002    7.616779
#3 14.45016 2003    7.722508
#4 13.29238 2004    7.664619
#5 14.81847 2005   20.596685
#6 14.36778 2006   20.091909
```